# is it possible to get an average of a set of numbers that is split across processes?

Tags: math, distributed, distributed-computing

Got a good answer on math SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864657/can-i-get-the-correct-average-of-a-set-of-numbers-from-the-averages-of-several-s

Let's say I have a stream of numbers:

```
565
212
812
895
443
73
468
900
299
993
252
740
291
112
(and thousands more)
```

Each message that I'm getting in contains the number and a few other things that need to be processed. Some of the processing may be time consuming so I'd like to split it into multiple processes. I'd like to send the numbers out to one of `n` processes in a roundrobin (or ZMQ router/dealer) style and do some processing on the numbers. The problem is that I'd like to keep a rolling average of all the numbers **across separate processes**:

`INPUT -> Worker #n -> Average collector -> OUTPUT`

If I split the numbers up into a group of three and take the average of the subset, then an average of the three averages, I get an incorrect result. Is it possible to split this work across multiple processes? The alternative would be to push just the numbers out to an `Averager` process. That seems fine but I wonder if there's a simpler solution that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

The question hinges on the notion of [sufficient statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic). In order to compute a statistic for the whole group, you need the sufficient statistics for each subgroup. For the mean, the sufficient statistics are the number of data for each subgroup and the total of the data for each subgroup. With those two items for each subgroup, you can exactly compute the mean for the whole group.

For the variance (equivalently, standard deviation) of the whole group, the sufficient statistics are the number of data, the total of the data, and the total of the squares of the data for each subgroup.

The sufficient statistics are not necessarily any more concise than the whole subgroup, but for the mean and variance, you need just a few items.

Comment: "you can exactly compute the mean for the whole group" -- how? If I put 3 numbers in a group, 6 in another and 5 in another and take the average of averages it doesn't match the average of the whole set.

Comment: Moved it here, looks like more of a math question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864657/can-i-get-the-correct-average-of-a-set-of-numbers-from-the-averages-of-several-s

Comment: @jcollum (whole mean) = (sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + ...) / (n1 + n2 + n3 + ...)